# How to automate this solution?

Tags: equation-solving

The Mathematica solver is strong. Of course, there is a room to improve it. Here is an example. The command

```
Reduce[x + 1/6*ArcCos[Cos[15*x] + 2*Cos[4 x]*Sin[2 x]] == Pi/12, x, Reals]
```

is running without any output for hours and the same issue with `Solve`. However, Mathematica is able to solve the equation under consideration. Taking into account the domain of `ArcCos` over the reals, one draws the bounds  `x >= Pi/12 - Pi/6 && x <= Pi/12` for the solutions. Now we transform the equation by

```
FunctionExpand[Cos[Pi/2 - 6*x] == Cos[ArcCos[Cos[15*x] + 2*Cos[4 x]*Sin[2 x]]]]
```

> Sin[6 x] == Cos[15 x] + 2 Cos[4 x] Sin[2 x]

. Then

```
Reduce[% && x >= Pi/12 - Pi/6 && x <= Pi/12, x, Reals]
```

> x == 2 ArcTan[
>       Root[1 + 12 #1 - 90 #1^2 - 196 #1^3 + 911 #1^4 + 376 #1^5 - 
>          2092 #1^6 + 376 #1^7 + 911 #1^8 - 196 #1^9 - 90 #1^10 + 
>          12 #1^11 + #1^12 &, 6]] || 
>    x == 2 ArcTan[
>       Root[1 - 16 #1 - 152 #1^2 + 528 #1^3 + 2908 #1^4 - 3280 #1^5 - 
>          15656 #1^6 + 3792 #1^7 + 28102 #1^8 + 3792 #1^9 - 
>          15656 #1^10 - 3280 #1^11 + 2908 #1^12 + 528 #1^13 - 
>          152 #1^14 - 16 #1^15 + #1^16 &, 9]]

```
 N[%]
```

> x==-0.12083||x==0.0923998

does the job. But the complicated result can be simplified in such a way

```
Cos[15 x] + 2 Cos[4 x] Sin[2 x] == Sin[6 x] // FullSimplify
```

> Cos[15 x] == Sin[2 x]

The rest is clear and we come to the explicit solutions

> x == [Pi]/34||x == - [Pi]/26

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `RootApproximant` transformation to `Simplify`:

```
eq = FunctionExpand[Cos[π/2 - 6 x] == Cos[ArcCos[Cos[15 x] + 2 Cos[4 x] Sin[2 x]]]];

Simplify[Solve[eq && x >= π/12 - π/6 && x <= π/12, x, Reals],
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, RootApproximant[#/π] π &}]
```

> $\left\{\left\{x\to -\frac{\pi }{26}\right\},\left\{x\to \frac{\pi }{34}\right\}\right\}$

Using the following transformation still doesn't guarantee exactness, but it might work better.

```
If[Rationalize[#/π, 10^(-10)] === Rationalize[#/π, 10^(-1000)],
   π Rationalize[#/π, 10^(-10)], #] &
```

Comment: +1 Or use `RootApproximant` with `NSolve` on the original equation 

`Pi*RootApproximant[(x /. 
     NSolve[{x + 1/6*ArcCos[Cos[15*x] + 2*Cos[4 x]*Sin[2 x]] == Pi/12, -Pi <= 
        x <= Pi}, x, Reals])/Pi]`

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this trick does not guarantee exact solutions. You are lucky.

Comment: It is easy to verify that the `RootApproximant` solution is exact in this case `x + 1/6*ArcCos[Cos[15*x] + 2*Cos[4 x]*Sin[2 x]] == Pi/12 /. 
  Thread[x -> sol] // FullSimplify`

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate your "It is easy to verify..."? I clearly understand the verification confirms the solutions obtained by RootApproximant. I repeat this approach does not guarantee exact solutions.

Comment: `Select[NSolve[{eq, -Pi < x <= Pi}, x, Reals] /. 
  n_Real :> Pi*RootApproximant[n/Pi], FullSimplify[eq /. #] &]` is guaranteed to only return exact solutions. For different equations you would in general have to adjust the interval of interest and/or the form of the `RootApproximant`. But this works as is for other equations such as `eq2 = x + 1/6*ArcCos[Cos[17*x] + 2*Cos[4 x]*Sin[2 x]] == Pi/12;`